# Check python code for second smallest in list

Tags: python, loops

I got this exercise: Take an unknown number of positive integers as input. Assume that the first
number is always smaller than the second, all numbers are unique and the
input consists of at least three integers. Print the second smallest integer.
I came up with this code:

```
    list=[10,12,1,3,2]
#find smallest number
if list[0]>list[1]:
    smallest = list[1]
else:
    smallest = list[0]
if smallest>list[2]:
    smallest = list[2]
    if smallest > list[3]:
        smallest = list[3]
        if smallest > list[4]:
            smallest = list[4]
#remove smallest number from list
list.remove(smallest)
#find smallest number in new list
if list[0]>list[1]:
    second_smallest = list[1]
else:
    second_smallest = list[0]
    if second_smallest > list[2]:
        second_smallest = list[2]
        if second_smallest > list[3]:
            second_smallest = list[3]
    print(second_smallest)
```

What can I do to simplify it?
Thanks!

Comment: Note: try not to use `list` as a variable name as it will overwrite the built-in `list()` function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use python's [list sort](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#sorting-how-to) method:

```
my_list = [10, 12, 1, 3, 2]
my_list.sort()
print(my_list[1])
```

Comment: that's O(n log n). works but there are better solutions in O(n)

Answer (score 1):

[`nsmallest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nsmallest) in `heapq` should be what you need:

```
>>> lst = [2, 21, 20, 63, 53, 0, 38, 20, 11, 26]
>>> from heapq import nsmallest
>>> nsmallest(2, lst)[-1]
2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first get the smallest number in the list with the `min` function.

```
num_list = [10, 12, 1, 3, 2]
min_num = min(num_list)
```

Then, make a new list by filtering out `min_num` so that the smallest number of the `filtered_list` is actually the second-smallest value of the initial list.

```
filtered_list = [n for n in num_list if n != min_num]
print(min(filtered_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
numbers = ...

smallest = numbers[0]
second_smallest = numbers[1]
for index in range(2, len(numbers)):
    number = numbers[index]
    if number < smallest:
        second_smallest = smallest
        smallest = number
    elif number < second_smallest:
        second_smallest = number

print(second_smallest)
```

This solution leverages the assumption that the first two numbers are in order. Of course if you're able to use python built-ins you can use this code:

```
print(sorted(numbers)[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = [10, 12, 1, 3, 2]
my_list.sort()
print(my_list[1])
```

In Case of duplication in list

```
my_list = [10, 12, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2]
my_list.sort()
mylist = list(dict.fromkeys(my_list))
print(mylist[1])
```

Comment: Before posting the codes, please check your codes first. The `list(dict.fromkeys(my_list))` doesn't guarantee list to be sorted.